# Is there elegant solution for mapping shell arguments to Python function arguments?

Tags: python

Imagine there is this Python function:

```
def frobnicate(foo, bar, buzz, *, quux, quuz=42, corge=None):
    pass
```

And I have a converter that makes it possible to call this function from the shell this way:

```
$ ./frobnicate.py 'I am foo' 'This is bar' --quux="Quux here" --buzz="Buzz value"
```

So, the rules are similar to Python calling syntax conventions — positional arguments go first, then keyword arguments can follow in an arbitrary order.

The question is — how can I allow positional arguments that have to start with double dash (`--`)? E.g. if I wanted to make `foo` equal to `--nonsense=1234`, how could I do that without forcing `foo` to be always specified as keyword argument? Are there are any more or less beautiful ways to do that without breaking the idea?

Comment: Shell conventions don't match Python conventions - in the shell, options go *first*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conventionally, options would go before positional arguments in the shell, and a bare `--` would mark an explicit end of options and beginning of positional arguments if you need positional arguments that look like options:

```
./frobnicate.py --quux="Quux here" --buzz="Buzz value" -- --nonsense=1234 bar
```

Comment: Do you know how is this convention called?

Comment: I don't think there's any standard name for it.